Find the conjugate function of $f(x) = ax + b$
This is the original function: $f(x) = ax+b$.
The conjugate function $f^*$ is defined by
$$f^*(s) = \sup_{x \in \text{dom} f} \Big \{ s x - f(x) \Big \}$$
I am given that $f^*(a) = -b$ but I don’t know how to prove this from the definition.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Substitute in the values you have. So $f^*(a)=\sup {ax-(ax+b)}=-b$.

I don't understand the question: $f$ is linear, so $sx-f(x)$ is also linear. Except when $s=a$, it is not constant, so it has no $\sup$. Is $f^\ast$ assumed to take values in $\mathbb R\cup {\infty}$?

The definition of the conjugate is:
$$
f^*(s) = \mathrm{sup}_{x \in \mathrm{dom}(f)} (s x - f(x))
$$
Where the domain of $f^*$ is over all $s$ such that the supremum is finite. This last part is important and is missing from your question as currently presented (but was included in the picture that you linked in the original question).
It is straightforward to apply this to a function of the form $f(x) = ax +b$.
Simply insert this into the definition:
$$
f^*(s) = \mathrm{sup}_{x \in \mathbb{R}} ((s-a) x - b)
$$
For most values of $s$, this supremum will be infinite. However, in the special case when $s=a$ the function inside the supremum simplifies to $-b$. Which is constant, so the supremum will also be $-b$.
So the domain of $f^*$ will be the set $\{a\}$ and the value at this point will be $f^*(a) = -b$.
